# How to remove dynamic divs with specific text only

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a drop down that dynamically creates divs for a sql report creator.

When selecting an option it creates a div with that option name and appends it to div correctly.  My problem is that I don't want duplicate divs.  So if a div with the ID and Text of "Successful" is already created, I don't want to add it, I want to remove the old one first, then add it.  As it stands now, the only part that doesn't work is:

```
 $("div").remove(divcnt);
```

Which does not remove the div with the same ID as the one selected.

Any suggestions?

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gmggq67o/

```js
$('#rp_status').on('change', function() {
  var divcnt = $(this).val();
  if (divcnt === 'All') {
    $("div").remove('.sselection');
    var $div = $("<div></div>", {
      id: "sall",
      class: "sselection status",
      text: divcnt
    });
    $("#status_selections").append($div);
  } else {
    $("div").remove(divcnt);
    $("div").remove("#sall");
    var $div = $("<div></div>", {
      id: divcnt,
      class: "sselection status",
      text: divcnt
    });
    $("#status_selections").append($div);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rp_item">
  <div class="rp_item_hdr">Status</div>
  <div class="rp_item_cnt">
    <select name="status" id="rp_status">
      <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
      <option>All</option>
      <option>New</option>
      <option>In Progress</option>
      <option>Successful</option>
      <option>On Hold</option>
      <option>Failed</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="report_selections" id="status_selections">
    <h5>Selections</h5>
    <div id="sall" class="sselection status">All</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to find a tag that has the given name. To select by the `id` property you need to prefix with a hash:

```
$("div").remove("#" + divcnt);
```

But be aware that this does not work for when `divcnt` has spaces, since HTML id attributes are not allowed to have spaces, and the selector will be interpreted differently. So use a custom attribute instead, or use the `[ ]` selector syntax:

```
$("div").remove('[id="' + divcnt + '"]');
```

Comment: yep, that's it.  Good catch, I thought I tried that earlier but must have messed something else up.

Comment: Just FYI, aside from the 'spaces in `id`' issue, this will result in the `#sall` element becoming `#all`.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was a typo, otherwise I don't understand why the OP would use `sall` instead of `all`. Seems to just complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is that because your `option` element values have spaces in the `id` attributes being generated are invalid. You can solve this issue by using a `data` attribute to contain a value to use as the `id` of the new content instead. Alternatively you could run the value through a regex to remove the spaces automatically; it just depends how much control you need of the value.

Secondly, as only one item can be selected, you can make the `remove()` call more generic by simply wiping all the `div` elements within the `#status_selections` before appending the new one. Try this:

```js
$('#rp_status').on('change', function() {
  var $container = $('#status_selections');
  $container.find('div').remove();
  $container.append('<div id="' + $(this).find('option:selected').data('id') + '" class="sselection status">' + this.value + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rp_item">
  <div class="rp_item_hdr">Status</div>
  <div class="rp_item_cnt">
    <select name="status" id="rp_status">
      <option selected disabled style="display: none" value=""></option>
      <option data-id="sall">All</option>
      <option data-id="new">New</option>
      <option data-id="inprogress">In Progress</option>
      <option data-id="successful">Successful</option>
      <option data-id="onhold">On Hold</option>
      <option data-id="failed">Failed</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="report_selections" id="status_selections">
    <h5>Selections</h5>
    <div id="sall" class="sselection status">All</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are correct, I do have spaces in the IDs.  I'll make that change as well.  Thanks,